# Sharing Redux store to multiple iframes using window or global scope

Tags: iframe, redux, react-redux

I have multiple iframes which need to share state, so that changes to the state in one iframe is reflected in the other iframe. I was looking into redux and having that globally scoped on the window so that both iframes have access to the store but wanted to get a second opinion and if anyone has experience doing this how I would go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Something that I found was if the iframes is a different host than the parent window, the iframes cannot write to that object. So if you want to do something like `window.parent.reduxStore = createStore(rootReducer)` then you need to be on the same origin. Other than that issue the store has been able to keep both iframes in sync and working well :)!!!